# Transpose the results of a MySQL query that outputs ranges

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My source table (wplott_wpkl_winner) contains the field "lottery_number" that carries 1 to 6 digit numbers and the corresponding "draw_date".

```
    lottery_number | draw_date
==================================
    0024           | 2018-11-10
    4456           | 2018-11-10
    3895           | 2018-11-10
    4557           | 2018-11-10
    4225           | 2018-11-10
    2896           | 2018-11-10
    3354           | 2018-11-10
    1895           | 2018-11-10
    78466          | 2018-11-10
    998556         | 2018-11-10
```

My current MYSQL query is as below (I am trying to group the data into ranges)

```
select
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 0 and 999 then 1 end) `0-999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 1000 and 1999 then 1 end) `1000-1999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 2000 and 2999 then 1 end) `2000-2999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 3000 and 3999 then 1 end) `3000-3999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 4000 and 4999 then 1 end) `4000-4999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 5000 and 5999 then 1 end) `5000-5999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 6000 and 6999 then 1 end) `6000-6999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 7000 and 7999 then 1 end) `7000-7999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 8000 and 8999 then 1 end) `8000-8999`,
        count(case when wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number between 9000 and 9999 then 1 end) `9000-9999`
    from wplott_wpkl_winner
    where CHAR_LENGTH(wplott_wpkl_winner.lottery_number) = 4 AND wplott_wpkl_winner.draw_date > '2013-06-30'
```

It provides the below output

```
    0-999 | 1000-1999 | 2000-2999 | 3000-3999 | 4000- 4999 .... etc
=====================================================================
    1     | 1         | 1         | 2         | 3
```

However, I would like to get the output in the below format.

```
    Range     | Count
=======================
    0-999     | 1
    1000-1999 | 1
    2000-2999 | 1
    3000-3999 | 2
    4000-4999 | 3
    .
    .
    .
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I did search in SO for a similar answer but none of the answers helped my particular case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses a series of unions:

```
SELECT
    `range`,
    count
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS pos, '0-999' AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM wplott_wpkl_winner
    WHERE draw_date > '2013-06-30' AND lottery_number BETWEEN 0 AND 999
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '1000-1999', COUNT(*)
    FROM wplott_wpkl_winner
    WHERE draw_date > '2013-06-30' AND lottery_number BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999
    UNION ALL
    ...      -- fill in remaining ranges here
) t
ORDER BY pos;
```

Note that I introduce a computed column `pos` so that we may maintain the desired ordering of the ranges in the final output.  Also, I removed the check on the `CHAR_LENGTH` of the `lottery_number`, since the conditional sums already handle this logic.

Comment: Why not `SELECT 1 AS pos, '0-999' AS range, COUNT(1) AS count FROM wplott_wpkl_winner WHERE draw_date > '2013-06-30' AND lottery_number BETWEEN 0 AND 999`?

Comment: @billynoah I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: I am using WpDataTables in wordpress to run this query. Seems like it does not support UNION statement :(

Comment: What is the error message?  Maybe it is from a problem with my code, not just union.  You're going to have to use union or some kind of cross tab functionality to generate the output you want.

Comment: Rendered query: SELECT range, count() FROM ( SELECT 1 AS pos, '0-999' AS range, COUNT(*) AS count FROM wplott_wpkl_winner WHERE draw_date > '2013-06-30' AND lottery_number BETWEEN 0 AND 999 UNION ALL SELECT 2, '1000-1999', COUNT(*) FROM wplott_wpkl_winner WHERE draw_date > '2013-06-30' AND lottery_number BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999) t ORDER BY pos ASC LIMIT 10
MySQL said: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range, count() FROM ( SELECT 1 AS pos, '0-999' AS range, COUNT(*) AS count FROM ' at line 1

Comment: @ThomasKoipuram `range` is a reserved MySQL keyword, and you should avoid using it to name your columns or output.  I have placed `range` into backticks, and it should work now.

Comment: Getting the below error now: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM ( SELECT 1 AS pos, '0-999' AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS count FROM wplott_wpkl' at line 1

Comment: I suspect that you are either not using my code, or you have made some changes which I can't see.  I have never heard of a version of MySQL which does not support union.

Comment: Tim, I removed UNION ALL after all ranges and it ran fine in PHPMYADMIN. However, in the plugin SQL editor I am getting the error: `cannot calculate position of (*) within UNION ALL SELECT 2, '1000-1999', COUNT(*) FROM wplott_wpkl_winner WHERE draw_date > '2013-06-30' AND lottery_number BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999 ) t ORDER BY pos;`

Comment: You may try using `COUNT(1)` instead.

Comment: Tried that and got similar error: `cannot calculate position of (1) within UNION ALL SELECT 2, '1000-1999', COUNT(1) FROM wplott_wpkl_winner WHERE draw_date > '2013-06-30' AND lottery_number BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999 ) t ORDER BY pos;`

Comment: Then maybe it doesn't support union.  You will have to find another way.

Comment: Thanks. Since it worked fine in PHPMYADMIN, the code is working as expected and I am marking this as the correct answer.